# Replace 0 in a column by the number of products that appear in another column in python

Tags: python, pandas

Good day

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
df: 
ID  |   Types of product    | Number of product
----|-----------------------|-------------------
1   | NDA,0D002             |                 2
2   | CALL'NA               |                 0
3   | MMCDP,PRCP,0D002      |                 3
4   | C0D002,CALL'NA        |                 1
5   | CALL'NA,NDA,HLA       |                 2
6   | CALL'NA               |                 0
7   | CALL'NA               |                 0
8   | 0D23, CALL'NA         |                 1
9   | SA,CALL'NA            |                 0
10  | IS,SA,CALL'NA,0D003   |                 1
```

My `df['Types of Products']` has data that contains different types of products, the column `df['Number of Products']` is then suppose to pick up how many types of  products there are and count them but then you find that there are zero entries in the `df['Number of Products']` column.
Please help me write a code that will assist with counting the correct number of products.

I wrote the following code to replace all the zeros with 1, but I doubt it is correct. Please help.

```
def product_value(df):
ProductNumber = df['NUMBER_OF_PRODUCTS'].astype(int)
NUMBER_OF_PRODUCTS = pd.Series(0)
for i in range(df.shape[0]):
    if  NUMBER_OF_PRODUCTS[i]==0:
        ProductNumber[i] = 1
return ProductNumber
```

Comment: So you want to count your number of Products. Can you explain a bit more why that number being 0 is a problem? If you count your number of products and the number of products is 0, then your count is 0. What exactly is the problem you're trying to fix here?

Comment: `df['Types of Products'].value_counts()`

Comment: I got my data from my database using SQL oracle. but some of the products have the same name but different product codes, so when i pull the data some product codes are not recognized that is why I got zeros I tried to upgrade my table in sql but it's still not helping, so i thought that i could maybe do the count of products using Python instead. @Zinki

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you need [`transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html) first for new `Series` with same size and then replace `0` values:

```
new=df.groupby('Types of product')['Types of product'].transform('size')
df['Number of product'] = df['Number of product'].mask(df['Number of product'] == 0, new)
print (df)
   ID     Types of product  Number of product
0   1            NDA,0D002                  2
1   2              CALL'NA                  3
2   3     MMCDP,PRCP,0D002                  3
3   4       C0D002,CALL'NA                  1
4   5      CALL'NA,NDA,HLA                  2
5   6              CALL'NA                  3
6   7              CALL'NA                  3
7   8        0D23, CALL'NA                  1
8   9           SA,CALL'NA                  1
9  10  IS,SA,CALL'NA,0D003                  1
```

Similar solution:

```
df.loc[df['Number of product'] == 0, 'Number of product'] = new
print (df)
   ID     Types of product  Number of product
0   1            NDA,0D002                  2
1   2              CALL'NA                  3
2   3     MMCDP,PRCP,0D002                  3
3   4       C0D002,CALL'NA                  1
4   5      CALL'NA,NDA,HLA                  2
5   6              CALL'NA                  3
6   7              CALL'NA                  3
7   8        0D23, CALL'NA                  1
8   9           SA,CALL'NA                  1
9  10  IS,SA,CALL'NA,0D003                  1
```